# Como Puedo realizar esta rejilla con bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tengo la sigiente rejilla realizada con CSS GRID

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Me piden que la realize usando el sistema grid de Bootstrap 4**. y por mas que intento no logro hacer que encaje. La verdad comienzo a preguntarme si realmente se puede realizar con Bootstrap.

este es mi avanze actual:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="my-section container-fluid">
      <div class="pt-5 row justify-content-center" style="height: 70vh;">
        <div class="container pt-5 " style="height: 100%;">
          <div class='row parent-wrap justify-content-center' style="height: 90%;">
            <div class="col-12 bg-danger h-100">
              <div class="row align-items-start ">
                <div class="col-4 bg-warning" style="height: 250px;">1</div>
                <div class="col-8 bg-info" style="height: 150px;">2</div>
                <div class="col-8 bg-success " style="height: 150px;">3</div>
                <div class="col-4 bg-warning" style="height: 250px">1</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Una aclaración: grid es una característica de css, no de bootstrap. Bootstrap es solo uno de los tantos frameworks css que existen y que desfavorecen el aprendizaje eel verdadero css.

Comment: Tienes la razon.  pero no veo a que viene eso.

Comment: Solo q me llamo la atencion el titulo de la pregunta, donde asocias la palabra grid a un "simple framework". Por cierto, sabes algo de css puro???

Comment: Claro amigo le digo asi porque el framework tiene un sistema para manejar el css grid de hecho asi lo llaman en su documentacion. Si se de css Y se perfectamente que se puede realizar muy rapido con CSS GRID pero no es el caso.

Comment: Menos mal. Yo conozco unos colegas que llevan tiempo usando tailwind y casi no saben nada de css (pero conocen lo q es css). Y lo peor: conozco a uno que usa reactjs y en una conversacion q tuve hace poco con el me di cuenta q no conoce el lenguaje javascript. Eso me hirvio la sangre. Esto es una de las muchas consecuencias de empezar a programar con frameworks en lugar de con lenguajes puros.